# useEffect doesn't trigger at all

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For some reason I cannot trigger my useEffect. It is a simple counter of seconds. I added console.log just to check if it will ever trigger but it doesn't at all. The interesting part is that React prints out the counter as 1. So I thought that it gets in the useEffect once and that's it but it doesn't print anything in the console at all. Any solutions?

```
const LookForRanked = () => {
   const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
        console.log(counter);
    }, 1000);


    return (
        <div className="time-searching">Searching: {counter} sec</div>}
    )

}
export default LookForRanked;
```

Comment: `useEffect` takes two arguments. The second argument could be undefined or an array of dependencies. It seems you got it mixed up with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Comment: The second parameter of useEffect method is dependency array, not timeout value.

Comment: *"but it doesn't print anything in the console at all"* - [It does for me.](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-euclid-u4nud7?file=/src/LookForRanked.js)  Prints two things actually.  The error telling you about the broken dependency array, and the output of `0` as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking `useEffect` for `setTimeout`. `useEffect` takes 2 parameters `useEffect(<function>, <dependency>)`. And that `<function>` runs every time there is a change in `<dependency>`.

Some examples of dependency:

1. No dependency passed:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on every render
});
```

2. An empty array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs only on the first render
}, []);
```

3. Props or state values:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on the first render
  //And any time any dependency value changes
}, [prop, state]);
```